# Re-Use of jQGrid Subgrids within Multiple Master jQGrid Pages

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have several fairly complex web pages (1000 lines of jQGrid in .js files) with different master jQGrids with more planned of the same basic design.  Each uses the same 3 subgrids with the first attached to the master, the second "appended" to the 1st, with the 3rd nested below the 1st subgrid.  About 80% of the jQuery/jQGrid code is common to all three.  It works very well. I would like to put the common subgrid code into a separate file so it could be loaded and shared across multiple pages.

I've experimented with jqGridExport/jqGridImport and it appears the idea there is to replace the whole thing, where I only want to bring in a snippet. I also noted that the export pushes all of the subgrid code out to a CDATA, which presumably could be imported.

How can I import a re-usable snippet of jQGrid subgrid code into the middle of a master jQGrid code for each separate page?

NOTE: I'm not trying to change imported subgrid code on-the-fly.  It is always the same, regardless of which master grid is loaded.